# Dual boot laptop, bitlocker blocked out windows. approach for reinstalling?

Tags: backup

pretty new to ubuntu and having some troubles with new setup.
Long story short got a new dell xps 9700 yesterday, it has 2 m.2 ssds so I installed linux on on and windows on the other. But as this is only my second linux install ever I forgot about tpm/bitlocker on windows. after getting all drivers and programs running on linux I went to swap back to windows and was locked out by bitlocker. I inserted the 40 digit key and then had the message that the boot drive was couldnt be accessed. I am now thinking that I should just reinstall windows but am unsure about the best way to do it so this doesnt happen again. can you please let me know if the my thoughts on the below steps will work?

Also, for ultra safety could I just physically remove the ubuntu m.2 ssd while I do the windows install to ensure that nothing gets repartioned/screwed... took ages to get all of the nvidia/sound drivers working. I have made a backup with time shift aswell.

info:

1. I have made a ubuntu backup with timeshift to a usb
2. I have a windows 10 bootable usb that I will use

Steps?

1. restart computer, enter bios and enable secure boot
2. select windows boot manager, start up. it will enter the recovery options.
3. select reinstall windows from usb bootable
4. install windows and once installed first thing disable bitlocker encryption
5. **What do I disable in bios regarding TPM??**
6. reboot, go into bios. disable secure boot, change ubuntu to boot manager again
7. should be able to switch between windows and ubuntu now?

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: Probably better suited for Superuser

Comment: since this question is about (re)installing Windows and/or fixing your bitlocker encryption, it's not on topic here.  You should ask about this somewhere that Windows is supported